# How to Linux get every IP address traffic on a single interface multi IP host

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, telegraf

In my scenario, my host has an interface but it has multiple IP addresses. I want to get the traffic of every IP address.I want to get received and sent packets and bytes, and error packets.
My interface is

```
qg-6108c4a2-94@if209: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:9e:58:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 173.20.12.8/24 brd 173.20.12.255 scope global qg-6108c4a2-94
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 173.20.12.7/32 brd 173.20.12.7 scope global qg-6108c4a2-94
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 173.20.12.11/32 brd 173.20.12.11 scope global qg-6108c4a2-94
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 173.20.12.13/32 brd 173.20.12.13 scope global qg-6108c4a2-94
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe9e:58d2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

how to linux get every IP address traffic in a single interface multi IP host?

Answer (score 0):

rx/tx statistics could be collected by adding some iptables rules and collect the counters.

As far as I konw, there is no way to collect per-host error packets.